# Issue with angular material and ng-messages

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

if I provoke 'min-length' error and then try to provoke 'required' error, the latter isn't shown, although the input is underlined in red.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label for="register_password">Password</label>
    <input required minlength="6" maxlength="100" type="password" name="register_password" id="register_password" ng-model="registerData.password">
    <div ng-messages="registerForm.register_password.$error">
        <div ng-message="maxlength">The password should be shorter</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">The password should be at least 6 characters long</div>
        <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Full working example:
http://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/mPEjYX

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like once any of the messages is shown, no other message will show again - even the same message.

Comment: @HanletEscaño
True, and if I emit 'required' restriction, ng-messages work as they should:
http://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/Myeqjw

Comment: @AndriusRimkus I wrote an answer. Can you confirm that ?

Comment: As I described in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45778833/7487135), you don't need to change your code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following code

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label for="register_password">Password</label>
        <input required minlength="6" md-maxlength="100"
               type="password" name="register_password"
               id="register_password" ng-model="registerData.password">
        <div ng-messages="registerForm.register_password.$error">
            <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength']">
              The password shold be at least 6 characters long</div>
 <!-- <div ng-message="minlength">The password should be at least 6 characters long</div> -->
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The password should be shorter</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
```

So there are many things you should consider. Since you are using angular material design I think you should use `md-maxlength` which will show a hint for how many charcters written against maxlength. I am not sure if there is any `md-minlength` directive is available. Now require and minlength is kind of same thing so I think you should combine those two as a single error message. Now There are some specific things releated to `[ngMessages][1]` check the documentaion for detail explation. I'll say couple of things about that. By default `ngMessges` only displays one error message and if there are more than 1 error message are valid then which ever comes first in `DOM` will be displayed. you can use `multiple` or `ng-messages-multiple`  to display more than 1 error messages. I suggest you should write you error in **incrementing order** like `required` first followed by `minlength`(If you want to display it seperately) and at the end `md-maxlength`. You can use `ng-message-exp` to combine more than 1 error codes.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply. I ended up combining ng-messages with ng-message-exp.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but there is one point.

You are using an old version of AngularJS Material.

If You change the last script with this lines then your code will be run properly.

```
    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <!-- Version 1.1.4 -->
    <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

[Check online](https://codepen.io/bahrampour/pen/ZJxQmz)

Good Luck